# How to find a given number by adding up numbers from list of numbers and return the used numbers?

Tags: c#, list, recursion, numbers, addition

'Sup everyone, I was trying to solve a problem which is pretty weird.
I'm gonna make an example to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I've got an array of uint.
Given a certain number "n", how do I find the only solution which gives me the numbers added up to reach "n"?
I'm talking of "the only solution" because there's only a solution to reach that number.

```
// This is not my array, but it's pretty similar.
// Given number: 96
// Used numbers to reach it: 32, 64

uint[] values = new uint[]
{
    1,
    2,
    4,
    8,
    16,
    32,
    64,
    128,
    256,
    512,
    1024,
    2048,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `values` is the list of all the powers of a number (in your example, powers of 2). Then you can just traverse the list of the powers from the back to the front to find the values that are higher than the number you are breaking a part and subtract them from the number (a greedy method):

```cs
private static IEnumerable<uint> FindParts(uint number, uint []powers)
{
    for (var i = powers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (number >= powers[i])
        {
            yield return powers[i];
            number -= powers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```cs
uint randomNumber = (uint)new Random().Next(4095);
var parts = FindParts(randomNumber, values);

Console.WriteLine($"{randomNumber}={string.Join('+', parts)}");
```

[See Live](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VT2Uwo)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a fairly simple math equation since all your numbers are powers of 2, you are better off going to a maths website to explore those options

However, here is a brute force combinatorial generic approach for any list of numbers

**Given**

unit sum extensions

```
public static uint Sum(this IEnumerable<uint> source)
{
   uint sum = 0;
   checked
   {
      return source.Aggregate(sum, (current, v) => current + v);
   }
}
```

A way to get combinations

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetCombinations<T>(T[] source)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < (1 << source.Length); i++)
      yield return source
         .Where((t, j) => (i & (1 << j)) != 0)
         .ToArray();
}
```

A way to filter targets

```
public static IEnumerable<uint[]> GetTargets(IEnumerable<uint> source, uint target) 
   => GetCombinations(source.ToArray())
      .Where(items => items.Sum() == target);
```

**Usage**

```
uint[] values = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, };

foreach (var found in GetTargets(values,96))
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", found));
```

**Output**

```
32, 64
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TBwVm2)

Note if you use this with any arbitrarily sized list, expect to wait many life times for the answer